# AppEngine Datastore: storing list of strings with more than 500 characters

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, requestfactory

My GWT Entity contains an attribute `myDescriptions` which is a list of 10 Strings with more that can have more than 500 characters.

When I try to give value to any element of the list, say element 3, two things can happen:
- `myDescriptions.get(3) = stringWithLessThan500Chars;` -> Is done correctly
- `myDescriptions.get(3) = stringWithMoreThan500Chars;` -> It is stored as **element 9** (last) as `datastore.Text`.

Any solutions for this? I tried creating myDescriptions as a list of `datastore.Text`, but I cannot access them from `EntityProxy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE has two string properties for Datastore types:

1. Short text string indexed property which stores up to 500 chars. In Java it's converted to `String`
2. Long text string unindexed property which stores up to 1MB of chars. In Java it's converted to `Text`.

In your case the solution is to iterate through list and replace `Text` with it's string value:

```
if(myDescriptions.get(x) typeof Text) {
    String text = ((Text) myDescriptions.get(x)).getValue();
    myDescriptions.set(x, text);
}
```